Diagnostic for GLM Gamma model in R
I am applying a glm model with gamma distribution and log link function to a continuous variable defined only on R+. I have tried to fit the model but I am having some difficulty interpreting the diagnostics. I haven't done it with glm before. I have read a bit and also seen other discussions on the matter. I would need some advice on interpreting the results, more to get feedback on what I think.
#fit a glm with gamma distribution gamma_fit <- glm(recoveries ~ loan_amnt+ term+ int_rate + installment + verification_status+ title+ fico_range_low + log(total_pymnt)+ total_rec_prncp + total_rec_int + total_rec_late_fee + last_pymnt_amnt + debt_settlement_flag, data = dati[train,], family = Gamma(link = "log")) 
summary(gamma_fit) 
vif(gamma_fit) 
predict_recoveries <- predict(gamma_fit, newdata = dati[test,], type = "response")
 rmse <- sqrt(mean((predict_recoveries - dati[test, "recoveries"])^2)) 
rmse deviance_residuals <- residuals(gamma_fit, type = "deviance") 

plot(density(deviance_residuals))
 lines(seq(-5, 5, 0.1), dnorm(seq(-5, 5, 0.1),0,1), col = "red")

library("boot")
 glm.diag.plots(gamma_fit)

library("DHARMa")
 sim_glm <- simulateResiduals(gamma_fit, n = 1000, plot = TRUE) plot(sim_glm)

my questions are about the output of glm.giad. and the simulation of residuals
From what I've read, diagnosing GLMs is difficult. The R^2 values should distribute like N~(0,1) (correct me if I'm wrong). glm.diag gives me the following output.
glm.diag
The fit seems fairly linear to me, what I don't understand is the qqplot, what is it against? Normal residuals? I'm not sure. That's why I found this second function that simulates residuals from the model and plots them against the calculated real ones.
DHARMa
here The qqplot in this case seems more reliable, should comes from simulation as far as i understood (in your opinion, is it good? Acceptable? I don't have enough experience to say for sure). What I don't understand is the plot on the right. If anyone can help me give a more thorough interpretation, I would greatly appreciate it.
